# iPhone app displays with black bars (3.5 inch) on iPhone 5 running iOS6 (but displays correctly on iOS7)

Tags: ios6, xcode5, iphone-5

I have an older app (originally developed for iOS3, but I've updated it over the years to support new features).  Prior to Xcode5 and iOS7, the iPhone 5 displayed properly (ie, I had included the proper launch screen to enable the 4 inch display).

Now, I'm updating the app using Xcode5, and it works properly on iPhone5 running iOS7 and on iPhone 4S running iOS6.  However, for an iPhone 5 running  iOS6, the app displays as a 3.5 inch app.

I tried updating to an asset catalog and making sure that all the iPhone launch images were accounted for, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the setting for your project so that it points to the Asset Catalog as the source for your Launch Image? I had the same problem as you have, but it turned out that from switching back and fort due to different problems I ended up thinking I was using the asset catalog when I was not.

In your project, you should see the same as in the picture below.

[image]